# Can't delete a element out of an collection in symfony2 project -> gives Error: Call to a member function removeElement() on a non-object

Tags: symfony, collections

In my project I have many forms with collections and adding and deleting goes fine.
But some at collections I can't manage to remove the element out of the arrayCOllections
it will give `Error: Call to a member function removeElement() on a non-object`
when the `$form->submit($request);` is processed, but the object exist.

The only difference I can see is that these collections are of non ORM handled entities but in pre-stored in my own arrayCollection that I create in the constructor

anyone an idea where to look

Not sure what code I should add to make it clear...

I am using the collections add/delete as mentioned in the symfony cookbook and it works fine with other collections

Comment: The error message makes it clear that your arrayCollection does not exist.   When Doctrine 2 retrieves an entity from the database, the entity's constructor is never called.  Is it possible that your non-ORM entities are built using some reflection based process?  If not then you just need to see what is making you arrayCollection go away.  Maybe post a bit of code.

Comment: Thanks for your thought, the 'ArrayCollection' did exist only somehow it wasn't an ArrayCollection anymore but an array. and array doesn't have ->removeElement()